# drilldown chart in Highcharts changes back button

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, drilldown

using highcharts drilldown with json data
highcharts.js
drilldown.js

I am able to drill down but i want to change the back button be a list on top
If you select the drill down you can click on the  link to bring you back to a beginning. Instead of click back, back, back
is this possible

Comment: Like breadcrumbs? Or just a "return to top" functionality?

Comment: Just on this what i am looking for is "breadcrumbs" link instead of the button

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap chart.drillUp() method and continue firing it until the top level series appear.

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'drillUp', function (p) {
      p.call(this);
      while (this.drilldownLevels.length) {
        p.call(this);
      }
    });
})(Highcharts);
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ubefcxtm/

The thing to be aware of is that it is does not drill up straight to the top-level series but it fires drilling up multiple times - e.g. drillup event also fires multiple times.